# Have Eclipse automatically import classes in jsp files specifically

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, intellisense

I'm a spoiled Java developer, and I like to hover over my missing classes and choose 'Import com.package.ClassName'.

How do you get Intellisense to work in jsp files?

Comment: Use IntelliJ.  It does it out of the box.

Comment: @Jim not sure why you edited jsp out of the question title

Comment: [Tags should not be appended to question titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/167443).

Comment: Yep, this is a problem in Eclipse specifically while editing JSP files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> the usual way to get the autocomplete with import has always worked for me in all Eclipse versions as far as I recall.

[image]

---

Indeed, most other helpful tooling like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (auto-organize imports), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (quick fix) and so on don't work in JSPs. But, after all, Java code [should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) be written in JSP files at all. It's not only a developing nightmare (as you encountered yourself in lack of proper tooling support in Eclipse), but it's also bad in all other colors. Just write Java code in normal Java classes.

Comment: It's not working on my fresh Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Kepler Service Release 1, any idea what might be cause for this?

Comment: Could be you're doing ctrl-1.  I can't get that working either.  Only ctrl-space works.